# How to find out how many strings are written into a binary file?

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, binaryfiles

I have a binary file `text.bin`. The text inside is written this way: 
`4helo5hello6helloo`. If I was not to know there are 3 strings inside, 
how would I find out? I want to make a dynamic array of strings from a 
binary file, but first I have to know how many strings there are in the file.
I know I can read it like this:

```
ifstream dat("text.bin", ios_base::binary);
if (!dat)
{
    cout << "Error";
    return 1;
}
int temporary;
dat.read((char*)(&temporary), sizeof(temporary));
char *arrray = new char[temporary];
dat.read(arrray, temporary);
string word = string(arrray, temporary);
```

How would I make this into a loop, so that it reads as long as there is something to read in the binary file? How would I find out how many words there are, so that I could prepare a dynamic array for the words? I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. If the binary format is like you said : 4helo5hello6helloo for example, do the following;

Read the first number,

substring from the position of the first number to however long the string is (the number you read),

Put the substring into a two-dimensional array (one dimension for the number of strings, the other for the length of the strings),

Wash rinse repeat until you reach the end of the file.

The length of the first dimension of the array is the number of strings in the file. The array now contains all the strings in the read file.

Cheers!

Comment: So you mean, i shoud use seekg(+length) and than counter++?

Answer (score 0):

For `4helo5hello6helloo`, write a separate function to iterate over `word` and at each numerical value increment the String array index by that value and increment a `word_counter variable` by 1 to get the number of words in your file.

The skipped indices contain your words (maybe write them to another array).

`read ()` function has a return type `size_t` and returns the number of bytes read from file, where a **return value of `0` signifies that end of file has been reached**.

```
int not_end = 1;
while (not_end)
{
    not_end = dat.read((char*)(&temporary), sizeof(temporary));
    char *arrray = new char[temporary];
    dat.read(arrray, temporary);
    string word = string(arrray, temporary); 
    // Note that word will get overwritten each time the loop is run
    // Store word in an array of Strings and keep incrementing index
}
```

Comment: So I should use a vector, or if I want to use dynamic field, I would just count how many times did the loop run until end, and use that counter to make a new dynamic array?

Comment: You can run the loop once at the beginning and use that counter to create your array. You can then use the array later to add words as you go. Do mark as accepted if that solved your problem :-)

Comment: no suitable conversion function from "std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>>" to "int" exists. It seems i cant put a char into an int. I cant write not_end=dat.read...

Comment: That is true - where are you getting this error. This seems to come from some other part of your code.

Comment: not_end=dat.read((char*)(&temp), sizeof(temp)); it is from here, dat.read() 
seems to return char type, and i am trying to save to int type not_end

Comment: Take a look at the man page for read [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

Comment: I dont know, the error is saying it returns char type. The page you sent me says it returns byte read value. I dont know where is the problem.
Same with the write() function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102499/discussion-between-madhav-datt-and-kira).